# Is there some other ways to prove "If $V,W$ are both finite-dimensional, then $L(V,W)$ is finite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, alternative-proof

I'd like to get some help proving the statement by using a contrapositive statement.

However, whenever I work on this proof, I always get stuck with showing $V$ or $W$ is infinite-dimensional.

Do I have to consider $Tv=0$ case to do it? for some $v \in V$.

If anybody can give me a hint proving this contrapositive statement, it would be really appreciated. I just want to widen my knowledge by proving something in different ways.

Comment: So you want to show that if $L(V,W)$ is not finite-dimensional, then at least one of $V$, $W$ does not have a finite basis? This seems unneccessarily complicated compared to starting from a finite basis if $V$ and $W$ and how to generate $L(V,W)$ from these

Comment: Yes, that was what I intended.

Comment: One of $V$ and $W$ being infinite-dimensional means that one of them does not admit a finite basis. How do you think you can show non-existence of a finite basis other than assuming existence and reaching a contradiction? Then you're back to the contrapositive of the contrapositive, so you can just use the straightforward direction to begin with.